# Stopping a sound loop with a button press

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a `IOPi` board attached to my `RPi`. I'm trying to have it play a sound when a button connected to the I/O pins is pressed.

This is achieved via a class and the only problem is that when the button is held down the sound is constantly playing. 
The code looks like this:

```
from ABElectronics_IOPi import IOPI
from time import sleep
import pygame
from inc import *
pygame.init()
global bus
InputPinNumber1 = 1
InputPinNumber2 = 1
bus1= IOPI(0x21)
bus2= IOPI(0x20)
while InputPinNumber1 <=34:
    bus1.setPinDirection(InputPinNumber1, 1)
    bus1.setPinPullup(InputPinNumber1, 1)
    bus1.invertPin(InputPinNumber1, 1)
    InputPinNumber1 +=1
    if InputPinNumber1 == 34:
    print("Bank 1 Ready ")
    break

while InputPinNumber2 <=34:
    bus2.setPinDirection(InputPinNumber2, 1)
    bus2.setPinPullup(InputPinNumber2, 1)
    bus2.invertPin(InputPinNumber2, 1)
    InputPinNumber2 +=1
    if InputPinNumber2 == 34:
    print("Bank 2 Ready ")
    break


class layout(object):
    def __init__(self, switch, bank, sound):
            self.switch=switch
            self.bank=bank
            self.sound=sound
            self.pre=0 
    def active(self):
                input1 = bus1.readPin(self.switch)
                input2 = bus2.readPin(self.switch)
            if(self.pre != input1) and (self.bank ==0):
                                    print("Button Press at pin " + str(self.switch))
                                    print("Switch " + str(self.switch))
                                    print("Bank " + str(self.bank))
                                    pygame.mixer.init()
                                    pygame.mixer.music.load(self.sound)
                                    pygame.mixer.music.play()
                                    sleep(3)
            if(self.pre != input2) and (self.bank ==1):
                                    print("Button Press at pin " + str(self.switch))
                                    print("Switch " + str(self.switch))
                                    print("Bank " + str(self.bank))
                                    pygame.mixer.init()
                                    pygame.mixer.music.load(self.sound)
                                    pygame.mixer.music.play()
                                    sleep(3)
```

Comment: `Self.` capital s is a typo?

Comment: Could you add the code that handles the button press please. Currently there is a bit too little to go on.

Comment: Yeah. My apologies, Its hard to use SO when using a iPhone

Comment: You are incrementing `PinReadNumber`... Why?

Comment: I am trying to increment PinReadnumber as I will have 32 pins wired to 32 buttons with a sound for each pin

Comment: This is really annoying me now. I have the board wired up to a button on pin 1. First press plays the pin 1 sound, second press plays pin 2 sound and so on. Any help would be very much appreciated